# How to clear rxjs stream events on the second component init

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I have a problem that after component is being destroyed and init again, all observables immediately fire the same events all over again which they fired before destroy.

For example a listener on current route parameters like here:

```
export class SomeComponent extends OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private alive = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.alive))
    .subscribe(params => console.log(params));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.alive.next();
    this.alive.complete();
  }

}
```

When I keep changing current route the console logs single routes - which is correct. But when I redirect to a different router and the component is destroyed, and then I go back again, I would immediately get something like:

```
{param: 1}
{param: 3}
{param: 2} // <-- those 4 are previous history
{param: 1}
{param: 5} // this is what I go back into
```

Looks like the events fire all at once all over again. Why does this happen? How can I solve this? I've tried unsubscribing, `takeWhile`, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActivatedRoute.params` is a `BehaviorSubject` so it emits its last value immediately on subscription.

If you want to ignore the first value you can use `skip(1)`:

```
this.route.params.pipe(
  skip(1),
  takeUntil(this.alive),
).subscribe(params => console.log(params));
```